# JTA and Hibernate Transaction management

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions, jta, message-listener

We have implemented a spring message listener service and the main operation exposed by this service is multiple event driven database update.

The context looks like as below.

```
   <bean id="consumerContainer"
        class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${jms.consumerContainer.concurrentconsumers}"/>
        <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="${jms.consumerContainer.maxconcurrentconsumers}"/>
        <property name="errorHandler" ref="errorHandler" />
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="destination" ref="listenerQueue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="consumerContainer" />
        <property name="receiveTimeout" value="10000" />
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager" />
    </bean>
```

TX manager is hibernate.

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
<bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>
```

and annotated the concrete class with @Transactional.

We use Jboss application server support to integrate with MQ via jndi.
The problem here is if there are any exception at any layer in the listener, the overall transaction is not getting rolled back and the message does not move to back out queue. It's obvious that as we use Hibernate transaction manager, it's not aware of other resource like JMS transactions.

Can I replace this safely with JTA transaction as Jboss will handle overall transaction management? Is there any foreseen risk in doing so?

I believe its no longer needed to annotate the class with @Transactional if we are using JTA as below.

```
<bean id="jtatxManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I replace this safely with JTA transaction as Jboss will handle overall transaction management?

Yes, you [can](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-programming-model). You should just change your bean `txManager` definition.

> I believe its no longer needed to annotate the class with `@Transactional`.

This is not true. You still need `@Transactional`. It allows spring to identify a transaction [boundary](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations).

Comment: Thanks SternK. Unfortunately that ran into an issue. We were using recieve time 1ms and JTA enabled this property to be in action that caused high MSU/MIPS at MF system.